# Forcing equal height child DIVs in a parent Bootstrap jumbotron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a newbie to Bootstrap and I'm having a problem getting two sibling columns to render to the same height under a parent DIV. Basically, I'm trying to create a "blackboard" next to the video which I'd like to render 100% with the video player but with a black background when the page loads.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Responsive Custom Video Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .jumbotron {
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .blackboard {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<div class="row jumbotron">
    <div class="player col-sm-6">
        <video width="100%" poster="videos/poster.jpg" id="videoPlayer">
            <source src="videos/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>

    <div class="blackboard col-sm-6">
        BLACKBOARD
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The "blackboard" DIV is only rendering the height of the text inside the DIV. The jumbotron's default background-color of #eee fills the rest of the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

This works but it seems a bit hacky. Add ID selectors to those two DIVs and:

```
// Force blackboard to the same height as the player.
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#blackboard").height($("#player").height());
})

$(window).resize(); // On page load
```